# Javafx pop up reminder as notification at certain time

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently designing a simple task managing program. I want to implement a pop up reminder function for my program.  i.e: users can enter some tasks to done by some date. eg: finish report by 2pm 12/10/2014.

I would like to use java or javafx to implement popup reminder where the software will pop a window like 1 hour before the event time.

I have searched on google but the results are mostly related to android programming. So could someone please share with me on what API i should use?  or provide me with a hint as to how to implement this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for a logic to implement the notification or you looking for a Control. If you are looking for a control, take a look at [ControlsFX Notification](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#notifications)

Comment: hmm, that looks possible. but how do i make the popup appear on a specific time or date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with ControlsFX notification for the notification window.

code sample:
Notifications.create()
.title("Task Reminder")
.text(eventDescription)
.showWarning();

I'm able to create a small pop up window at the bottom right of the screen. 
However, to use the code, you need to add ControlFx to the project library. 
And make sure to put the code at where the UI Application is because Javafx only works in the UI tread.

As for the date comparison, just use java Calendar.It has useful APIs in it.